# How to change a image size in uiimage picker controller

Tags: ios, camera, uiimageview, uiimage, swift3

The following code takes a picture and the displays on a uiimageview. The pitcure fills the whole uiimageview. How Can I make the image appear smaller so that the image saved is not all of the screen. I would like there to be a border around the picture taken. A rectangle border. Thanks.

```
@IBAction func Camera(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera){
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)}}

            func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject: AnyObject]!){
                cameraScreen.image = image
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
                screenView = UIImageView()

                screenView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)





                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.cameraScreen.frame.size)
                self.view.drawHierarchy(in: self.view.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)



}
```

Comment: Do you want to scale image that you got from image picker completion handler?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method which you have to call in didFinishPickingImage completion handler.

```
func resizeImage(image: UIImage, newWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage {

  let scale = newWidth / image.size.width
  let newHeight = image.size.height * scale
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight))
  image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight))
  let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

  return newImage
}
```

This method will change size of the image.

Comment: CGSizeMake it is not available in Swift 3

Comment: How would I write didFinishPickingImage completion handler? Is this accurate func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {        
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage{
            dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { self.customFunction(pickedImage)} )   
        }else{
            dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }
    }.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Kirti Parghi's answer to Swift 3

```
func resizeImage(image: UIImage, newWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {

    let scale = newWidth / image.size.width
    let newHeight = image.size.height * scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```